# Blurred and transparent button background

Tags: javascript, css, button, background

I have a button on top of a div with image background, I need buttons background to be transparent with blur effect - like in iOS7.

I know there's a css property filter:blur(2px) - is it possible to use it on buttons background only?

If not CSS, maybe there are any other solutions? js?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following:

[Background blur with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565520/background-blur-with-css)

The third answer seems like what you're looking for.